# calloc, malloc and dynamic struct allocation

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, structure, calloc

I am trying to dynamically allocate an array of structures in c so that I can refer to them the same as if I had done a static declaration.  I understand that calloc() does the additional step of initializing all the allocated memory to 0.  But, other than that, are the 2 completely interchangeable for the following code?  If I am using fread() and fwrite() to get these data structures in and out of a file, does calloc() help or hinder this?

```
#define MAGIC   13
    struct s_myStruct {
int a[6000][400];
int b[6000][400];
int c[6000][400];
};

struct s_myStruct stuff[MAGIC];
vs
struct s_myStruct *stuff = calloc(MAGIC, sizeof(s_myStruct);
```

Thank you.

Comment: What does this have to do with files?

Comment: Also you can use the "universal zero initializer" for your array: `struct s_myStruct stuff[MAGIC] = {0};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're not the same. Declaring the data like this:

```
struct s_myStruct stuff[MAGIC];
```

will leave the memory uninitialized if you're declaring it in function scope (which you must be, given the second choice). Adding `= {0}` before the semicolon rectifies this.

The second choice, of using calloc, allocates the memory on the heap.

There's always a difference though: `sizeof(stuff)` will be 13 * sizeof(struct s_myStruct) in the first case, and the size of a pointer in the second case.

Comment: Are you saying then that the 2 cases are entirely different, and that in the second case all I have done is allocate storage for pointers to structures, and not to the structures themselves?  And therefore I would need another step to allocate storage for the structs?

Comment: No, they're mostly the same -- I just enumerated some of the differences.

Answer (score 0):

You really don't want to do the first one, as you'd be putting 13 * 3 * 6000 * 400 * 4 = 370MB on the stack.

But this has nothing to do with using `fread` and `fwrite`.

Comment: I wasn't intending to put stuff[MAGIC] on the stack; it is a global.

Comment: @user994179: In that case, there will be very little difference in practice, other than that you will need to `free` the dynamic version at some point.  Also, as @Paul mentions in his answer, arrays and pointers have some subtle differences in behaviour.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance here, but if, as Paul says, I am only allocating storage for pointers to the structures rather than the structures themselves, the 2 cases (static vs dynamic) I presented are completely different, and that I need to do something else if I want to use the dynamic route?